# php redirect previous TWICE

Tags: php, browser-history

I have looked around on the web and have found a code to redirect previous ONCE, but I would like to redirect previous twice?

Is there a special function to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be via JavaScript.

```
<script>window.history.go(-2);</script>
```

Doing it via PHP would be tricky, as you'd have to keep track of the user's successive `HTTP_REFERER` values in a session or cookie or something, which'd be glitchy if the user had multiple tabs open on your site.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I just did `echo '<script>window.history.go(-2);</script>';
exit();`

Comment: Accept this answer, then. Click the checkbox next to it, and go do it for your other questions or you'll find people not answering you as often.